# Xcode fails on Kotlin Multiplatform due to "Execution failed for task ':core:linkReleaseFrameworkIos'"

Tags: swift, xcode, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Since `core` is how we named the pod to handle KMM from Xcode, what the hell is `linkReleaseFrameworkIos`? 
Everything worked perfectly before, but now my Xcode gives me error saying

`Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`
`* What went wrong:`
`Execution failed for task ':core:linkReleaseFrameworkIos'.`

I tried:

- Pod reinstall
- Clean project
- Delete derived data
- Gradlew clean(success), Gradle build(failed), Gradlew linkReleaseFrameworkIOS(failed) commands

nothing helped.

Comment: Could you please extend the question with `./gradlew linkReleaseFrameworkIos -i` output?

Comment: I will post an answer soon. Solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**
Bumped the ktor version to `1.6.1` and coroutines version to `1.5.0`. 
They did not match for some reason.